# SQL Loader when statement

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

When I added "when" statement, I got error:
Illegal combination of non-alphanumeric characters.

```
load data
preserve blanks
into table table_name truncate
when (field_name > '0010000')
(
.....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> and < not accepted in sql loader
>   in this case used 
>   when (1:3) != '000'

Comment: Please edit and add this to your original post, then delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid only `'='`, `'!='` or `'<>'` are allowed as operators in the when clause.
More info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657